# Extending the ZeroMQ Majordomo Pattern to have Multiple Brokers

Tags: c, sockets, design-patterns, zeromq, broker

I am attempting to extend the ZeroMQ Majordomo Pattern to operate with multiple brokers interconnected in a mesh network. It will operate identically to the original Majordomo Pattern except a broker B1 will forward a client request to broker B2 if B1 cannot service its client's request but B2 can.

I have two design questions about the implementation of this pattern.

**1) How will broker B1 know what services are available on B2?**
One possible solution is to create a "hash node" that connects to and keeps track of services available by each broker in the mesh. And when a broker wants to forward a client request it consults the hash node. However this requires all brokers to regularly communicate with the hash node. Will this communication hinder performance or create any subtle issues I didn't mention?

**2) What kind of sockets should brokers use to communicate in a mesh network?**
Each broker clearly needs a ROUTER socket to receive messages, connection request, etc.. But what socket type should each broker use to send requests? A DEALER socket is a poor choice because each broker will need to open a DEALER socket to every other broker. ROUTER would be nice but requires "hacks" to implement. Is there any other way to efficiently connect brokers together?

Comment: Just a note, since this one hasn't gotten much attention, I want to take some time and write up a response for you just haven't had time yet.

Comment: I've just started looking for the same solution. Please update the question if you have made any progress so far. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @john,
You have any success in this?